# Why is mapbox searchbox crashing my app upon interaction?

Tags: java

I followed a mapbox search setup [tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/guides/places/#add-autocomplete) to implement it in my code but as soon as I type a letter on the search field, my app crashes.
I believe that this is the error that matters here.

```
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.places.autocomplete.viewmodel.PlaceAutocompleteViewModel.onQueryChange(PlaceAutocompleteViewModel.java:87)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.places.autocomplete.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment.onQueryChange(PlaceAutocompleteFragment.java:155)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.places.autocomplete.ui.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:82)
```

I'm using java8 with min android version of 21 (Lollipop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using java 8, please check if you have added this code block inside `android{ }` in your app-level `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

This is usually overlooked in many projects that uses java 8.

Comment: It's working now! This has been very hard to solve and very frustrating since the error doesn't really show any connections with Java 8 support. Thanks!